Error in device registration in Google Assistant
I followed the instructions to add Google Assistant to my Raspberry Pi 4. And in the step where I needed to register device for Assistant APi, it throws this error

Reached limit on number of clients in this project.Try in a new project

Click here for details about error
Even through I tried to create another project, or with another email, the result stayed the same. In the instruction, they can easily get through it.

Potential duplicate, if it would have and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78861026/18667225

I read that one before and there is no answer.
